# Archive block for nodes using Views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

How can I create an archive block like this, only for Drupal 7 (views 3)
http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-create-monthly-archive-block-drupal-blog-views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the "Contextual Filter" for this. Choose the "Content: Created date" as the contextual filter. Then in the filter settings, choose "Display a summary" and save the view. Maybe this helps you to start with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this through searching. So for the completeness of the thread, here is a full tutorial covering how to create an archive block om Drupal 7: http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views

Answer (score 0):

These are all fine and correct answers but fail to address the need for a Year to Month drill down. A client has a Views Accordion archive which has months as the top level. It has been difficult to turn this archive into one which nests the months inside of a specific year, such that the accordion shows years as the top level, and subsequently has each month of the year nested inside. There are a few template based solutions out there but none that seem to work with an accordion UI. Contextual filters don't seem able to handle this scenario.