# D7 Views 3 Blog Archive Block

Tags: 7, blocks, views, nodes

I need to build a "blog archives" block with Views 3. I've seen (and am currently using) the solution at [Archive block for nodes using Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/archive-block-for-nodes-using-views), but this method doesn't allow specific enough paths.

Following the linked method, the summary output relies on the selected context filter. For example, if you use **Content: Created Year+Month**, your links turn out like **base_path/YYYYMM** - no separation between month and year. Likewise, if you use the **Content: Created Year** or **Content: Created Date** contextual filters you get a string output... not that great for organization.

Is it possible to generate a link path like **base_path/YYYY/MM** instead of a mixed string? I have attempted to create this solution using aggregation, count and grouped Views fields with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create 2 views, one which takes Year argument with path `base_path/yyyy` and another that takes 2 arguments with path `base_path/yyyy/mm`

And you have to create a custom module which defines a [`hook_block_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [`hook_block_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7). This block will basically read your node table for blog type posts, and build links to the 2 views you created above, structured in Year > Month hierarchy. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Nice, totally didn't think of doing it this way. It might work like that with an embedded view too, and passing the second argument... thanks man